# How to trigger OnCommandClick first than OnClientClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dom-events

I am creating a session inside the **OnCommandClick** to save information about a file that will be downloaded. 
If I click to download it, the **OnClientClick** works fine and I can download the file.

But when I have a grid with more than one file, I think that the function **OnClientClick** is being fired first than **OnCommandClick**, so the session is being updated after the download, so I always get the wrong file. Just when I click again at the same file is that the correct one comes (because probably the session was updated after the first click).

For example: files 1, 2, 3 and 4... if I click at file 1, it downloads ok, but when I click at file 2, it downloads the file 1 again, then if I click in file 4, it downloads the file 2, if I click 3, it downloads file 4, always the previous one.

Can I force the **OnCommandCLick** to run first than **OnClientClick** to try to solve this problem?

Comment: Is there any event exists  for ASP button with name OnCommandCLick ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnClientClick` always gets called first. I suggest getting rid of `OnClientClick` and move the file download code to the server-side event `OnCommandClick`, right after updating the session.

You can either use FileStream or inject a javascript code that will start the file download.